# What should the correct query for this problem?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, union, where-clause

Well guys, I have a problem, I have 4 tables that I will summarize.

This database is on PostgreSQL, and the model relationship is an inherit

TABLE 1: (Person)

```
id: character
name: character    
last_name:character    
age: character
```

---

TABLE 2: student (Inherit from Person)

```
id: character (imported from person)         
name: character (imported from person)        
last_name:character (imported from person)        
age: character (imported from person)    
college: character    
courses: character
```

---

TABLE3: teacher (Inherit from Person)

```
id: character (imported from person)        
name: character (imported from person)        
last_name:character (imported from person)        
age: character (imported from person)    
license: integer    
date_empl: date
years_working: integer
```

---

I want that with a single query, get all the information of one of the two tables, to which the code belongs, of course.

I can not do

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT
WHERE ID = {{whatever}}
```

because is static, and I want to search the `(ID {{whatever}}` in the other table.

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT
WHERE ID = {{whatever}}

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM TEACHER
WHERE ID = {{whatever}}
```

but it does not work because `UNION` needs to have the same number of columns in the 2 tables

How could I get the detail of a person, be it professor or student, with only one query? Or in what way could I do it?

Comment: What do you mean saying "inherited"? Does Postgress support object tables? Or it's just a traditional relational DB? So, do all 3 tables exist? Or the Person table is an abstract "template" rather then a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `UNION` is a solution. When columns are different, you can generate several columns in the output, and fill them with `NULL` in records where they are not available.

```
SELECT id, name, last_name, age, college, courses, null, null FROM student
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, last_name, age, null, null, license, date_empl FROM teacher
```